# How can I display a Latex Formula in a Tooltip from Materialize using MathJax?

Tags: html, css, latex, materialize, mathjax

I'm using Materialize to display a tooltip like so:

```
<div class="center-align default-tooltip">
    <a class="btn tooltipped"
    data-position="bottom"
    data-html="true"
    data-tooltip="
        <div class='default-tooltip-text'>
            \( f(x) = mx + c \). 
        </div>
     ">
         Hint!
     </a>
</div>
```

To display "regular" latex stuff I use MathJax. It renders everything normally, except when I put it in a tooltip, where it just shows "\( f(x) = mx + c \)" but not in latex style. 
The two classes default-tooltip(-text) are unlikely to interfere, but I'll add them here for completeness:

```
.default-tooltip-text {
    text-align:justify;
    font-size: 16pt;
    line-height: 1;
}

.material-tooltip {
    width:50%;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like MathJax runs on page load at which point it converts your formula to actual HTML elements that look as you expect them to. Whereas Materialize takes the value of data-tooltip when an element is hovered over. Therefore your MathJax needs to be run again when the hover occurs. You may also consider posting a demo to JS Fiddle or some such site as there are several pieces at play here

Comment: You were exactly right. The hover creates a new div that holds the tooltip content. Now, the problem is that I need to do the typesetting again by MathJax like described here https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html. It's just that it won't work yet (won't even throw any errors either). But that comment already helped a lot. thanks.